# std::function with templated arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, functional-programming, template-argument-deduction

I want to write a templated function that applies some function over pairs of elements coming from two vectors. The result should be a new vector of results. I want this to be a templated function so that it works on different types.

I tried the definition before. However, when I try to apply it to some particular function, I get a compilation error.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
vector<T3> mapzip2(const vector<T1> &xs, const vector<T2> &ys, std::function<T3(T1, T2)> l) {
    if (xs.size() != ys.size())
        throw runtime_error("mapzip2: container sizes (" + to_string(xs.size()) + 
                            " and " + to_string(ys.size()) + ") do not match");
    vector<T3> result;
    result.reserve(xs.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < xs.size(); i++)
        result.push_back(l(xs[i], ys[i]));

    return result;
}

constexpr double PRECISION = 1E-6;

bool feq(double a, double b) {
    return abs(a - b) < PRECISION;
}

int main() {
    vector<double> a = {0.3, 0.42, 0.0, -7.34};
    vector<double> b = {0.3, 0.42, 0.0, -7.34};

    // compilation error: no matching function for call to 
    // ‘mapzip2(std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&, bool (&)(double, double))’
    vector<bool> result = mapzip2(a, b, feq);

    for (bool b: result) cout << b << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

What is wrong here with types deduction?

Comment: Your types don't make much sense. `T3` will resolve to a function pointer so you don't have to use `std::function` here. But then there's the issue that you try to return a `T3` from your function which is weird. What are you really trying to return? Should it return a `bool` if you call it with `feq`?

Comment: I suggest you take a hint from all C++ standard library functions taking a callable objects, and use plain template arguments for it. All you need is `T3` and then have the argument `T3 l`.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude That won't work with the return type.

Comment: @SombreroChicken It will if the rest of the code is "fixed" to be consistent with the return type, and not use `T3` for return type or `result` vector type.

Comment: Indeed, that's why my initial comment

Comment: I think intended return type for mapzip2 was `std::vector<T3>`...

Comment: By the way, what you seems to want to do with this `mapzip2` function is what's done with the two-input overload of [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: Yes, return type is supposed to be `vector<T3>` - I will fix it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a sort of chicken-and-egg problem.

The `T3` type in

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
T3 mapzip2(const vector<T1> &xs, const vector<T2> &ys, std::function<T3(T1, T2)> l)
```

has to be deduced from the third argument, a `std::function<T3(T1, T2)>`

But when you call

```
bool feq(double a, double b) {
    return abs(a - b) < PRECISION;
}

// ...

    vector<bool> result = mapzip2(a, b, feq);
```

you call `mapzip()` with `feq` that can be converted to a `std::function<bool(double, double)>` but **isn't** a `std::function<bool(double, double)>`

So the `T3` type can't be deduced as `bool` because to convert `feq` to `std::function<bool(double, double)>` you have to know, **before** the deduction, that `T3` is `bool`.

Possible solutions:

(1) explicit the template types calling `mapzip()`

```
vector<bool> result = mapzip2<double, double, bool>(a, b, feq);
```

This way the compiler know that `T3` is `bool`, so convert `feq` to `std::function<bool(double, double)>`

(2) construct a `std::function<bool(double, double)>` with `feq`

```
vector<bool> result = mapzip2(a, b, std::function<double, double, bool>{feq});
```

so the compiler can receive a `std::function` as third argument and deduce `T3` from it.

(3) (more flexible and, IMHO, the best of the three) avoid `std::function` and use a more generic functional typename for the function

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename F>
auto mapzip2(const vector<T1> &xs, const vector<T2> &ys, F l) {
    if (xs.size() != ys.size())
        throw runtime_error("mapzip2: container sizes (" + to_string(xs.size()) + 
                            " and " + to_string(ys.size()) + ") do not match");

    vector<decltype(l(xs[0], ys[0]))> result; // <-- use decltype() !

    result.reserve(xs.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < xs.size(); i++)
        result.push_back(l(xs[i], ys[i]));

    return result;
}
```

Observe the use of `decltype()` to deduce the type of the returned vector (the old `T3`) and the use of `auto` (starting from C++14) for the returned type of the function.

If you can't use C++14 (only C++11), you have to add the trailing return type

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename F>
auto mapzip2(const vector<T1> &xs, const vector<T2> &ys, F l) 
    -> std::vector<decltype(l(xs[0], ys[0]))>
 {

 }
```

Observe also -- as pointed by ypnos in a comment -- that the signature of your original `mapzip2()` is wrong: you return `result`, a `std::vector<T3>`, not a `T3`.

Comment: To fix it, the signature could be changed to `vector<T3> mapzip2(const vector<T1> &xs, const vector<T2> &ys, T3(*l)(T1, T2))`

Comment: `decltype` is the saviour. I was trying to use `std::function` just because I didn't know how to handle the type of return vector.

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka - yes: `decltype()` is extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that template functions don't infer types and don't do implicit casting (if you don't supply the types, just let the compiler generate the function). The compiler just tries to find a simple match. Consider this example:

```
template<typename T>
T add2(T a, T b)
{
    T res = a + b;
    return res;
}


int main()
{
    int a = add2(10, 20);  // ok
    double b = add2(10.2, 20); // error, no implicit cast from int to double

    return 0;
}
```

The second assignment in `main` will emit `no matching function for call to ‘add2(double, int)’` error.

As in your case, you pass `feq` which is of type `bool (*)(double, double)`, that is, it's a function pointer, while `mapzip2` expects `std::function` object. There is no implicit casting for templates.

As others suggested, you can build the function object explicitly. 
(also as others noted, you need to return `vector<T3>`, not just `T3`, but this is a second problem, not related to the original one).

Finally, if you do supply the template types, the compiler will indeed try implicit casting, for example, in the above example, the following will work:

```
double b = add2<double>(10.2, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Standard Library solves this issue by using iterators. It would be a good idea to use them too since your code has the same structure as a standard algorithm:

```c++
// Overload #1
template<class I1, class I2, class O, class F>
void zip(I1 begin1, I1 end1, I2 begin2, O out_it, F f) {
  while (begin1 != end1) {
    out_it++ = f(*begin1++, *begin2++);
  }
}

// Overload #2
template<class C1, class C2, class R, class F>
void zip(C1& c1, C2& c2, R& ret, F f) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  zip(begin(c1), end(c1), begin(c2), std::back_inserter(ret), f);
}

vector<bool> result;
zip(a, b, result, feq);
```

Or just use [`std::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

If you still want to return the vector from the function, it would help to decouple the return type deduction from the function itself:

```c++
template<class T> using value_t = typename std::decay_t<T>::value_type;
template<class F,class... Cs> using zip_ret = std::result_of_t<F&(value_t<Cs>...)>;

template<class C1, class C2, class F, class R=zip_ret<F, C1, C2>>
std::vector<R> zip(C1& c1, C2& c2, F f) {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    std::vector<R> ret;
    std::transform(begin(c1), end(c1), begin(c2), std::back_inserter(ret), f);
    return ret;
}
```